# Is there a way to introduce a small delay between each unittest case?

Tags: python, unit-testing, qemu

i'm testing an application inside a docker container, and it seems that the application crashes for some virtualization reason (i'm forced to use an qemu emulated amd64 container on an M1 Mac).

I've read that the qemu layer stability is I/O sensible. Is there a way to slow dow the unittest runner, possibly with a delay/sleep time between each test ?

Thx in advance

Comment: Probably, but you'll need to tell us about your test framework first.

Comment: Most test frameworks have an option to execute some code after all parts with something like a `@After` annotation or similar. Just put a sleep in something like that.

Comment: hum.. no specific framework.. i'm using the unittest to validate a non-python web application. more like an integration test. Typically something like "unittest -> curl the following asset, assume that we have a 200 status"

Comment: thx @JoachimSauer, i've just found a "tearDown" method that i could use..

Comment: If you find yourself needing a delay between unit tests - its a code smell. Unit tests should be completely self contained, independent from each other and any other external influences like data base connections or time delays.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to insert some sleep time in the `setUp` or `tearDown` methods, you can subclass and override the default `TestResult` by doing something like this:

```
import time
import unittest

class SlowTestResult(unittest.TestResult):
    def startTest(self, test):
        time.sleep(1)
        super().startTest(test)

slowTestRunner = unittest.TextTestRunner(resultclass=SlowTestResult)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=slowTestRunner)
```

Comment: .. so easy... for sure !